# Initializing structure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

I am trying to initialize a structure in MATLAB similar to how C code does

```
typedef struct{
 float x;
 float y;
} Data

Data datapts[100];
```

From MATLAB, I know this is how to create a structure:

```
Data = struct('x', 0, 'y', 0)
```

but how do you create 100 instances of it?

Or is this not usually done in MATLAB?  Does MATLAB prefer dynamic allocation whenever there is new data to add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
repmat(Data,100,1);
```

You can assign data to it with:

```
Data(1).x = 10;
Data(1).y = 20;
```

Comment: Don't you need `Data = repmat(Data,100,1)` to assign the "answer" to a new structure ?

Answer (score 13):

I don't know C, so I don't know how your code initializes the structure. However, consider these two possibilities:

#### 1. A struct *array* `data` with 100 elements, each of which has two fields `x` and `y`

You can initialize an empty struct with

```
data = struct('x', cell(100,1), 'y', cell(100,1));
```

and you access each element of the struct array as `data(1)` and each of these is a struct. Typically, these are used when you have several equivalent "things" with the same set of properties, but different values for each.

#### Example:

```
elements = struct(...
    'name',         {'Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium'},...
    'atomicWeight', {1, 4, 7}, ...
    'symbol',       {'H', 'He', 'Li'});

elements(1)
ans = 

        name: 'Hydrogen'
atomicWeight: 1
      symbol: 'H'
```

So you can access each individual struct to get to its properties. Now if you wanted to append a struct array with the next 10 elements to this list, you can use `cat`, just like you would for matrices.

#### 2. A struct `data` with two fields `x` and `y`, each with 100 elements

You can initialize this as

```
data = struct('x',zeros(100,1),'y',zeros(100,1));
```

and you access each element of the field as `data.x(1)`. This is typically used when you have one "thing" with several properties that can possibly hold different values.

#### Example:

```
weather=struct('time',{{'6:00','12:00','18:00','24:00'}},...
    'temperature',[23,28,25,21]);
```

Once you understand structs and struct arrays and how they're used and indexed, you can use them in more complicated ways than in the simple illustration above.

Comment: Your 2nd example is basically the same as the 1st one. To get 1x1 structure you have to put cell arrays into double curly brackets `{{...}}`.

Comment: @yuk Ah, yes. Thanks. I wrote it without MATLAB, so missed that :)

Comment: The question isn't about initialization. It's about instantiation. In C, the "typedef struct{...} Data" is merely a blueprint for a struct. To actually create an instance of that struct, you have to instantiate it (for example, "Data datapoint;"). I don't think MATLAB has any way to do proper object-oriented programming, so there is no answer to his question. Your proposed solution here, however, is a good idea for a workaround!

EDIT: Nevermind! You *can* create blueprints, they just have to be classes! Answer coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other methods described by @yoda and @Jacob, you can use `cell2struct`.

Answer (score 1):

While each of the other answers are helpful, they don't actually address the question. If you would like to create a data structure that is only a blueprint until you instantiate it, you have to use a [class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/create-a-simple-class.html).

Here's a class that will do the trick. Refer to the documentation for details on file structure.

```
classdef Data
  properties
    x = 0  % If you don't want to initialize upon instantiation,
    y = 0  % you could instead have x/y {mustBeNumeric}
  end
end
```

Then, instantiate it by calling `dataPoint = Data` and use repmat to make 100 as you desire.